# Discord.py creating role off of a list

Tags: discord.py

Ive seen examples on how to give a role to a user, but those are hard coding the role into the add_role function. I would like help in writing a command that allows a user to assign a role themselves based off a list.

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def assign(ctx, role):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name = role)
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
    await client.say("Role added! {}".format(member.mention))
```

this is the code i got, but this assigns any role in the server, since thats what ive assigned role to apparently. Ive played around with other things but ive gotten an error, 'str' object has no attribute 'id' error.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a whitelist of role names, then check against that list before assigning the role.  In the below I also use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters), but you could look up the name as well.

```
roles_whitelist = ['librarian', 'treasurer', 'secretary']

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def assign(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    member = ctx.message.author
    if role.name.lower() in roles_whitelist:
        await client.add_roles(member, role)
        await client.say("Role added! {}".format(member.mention))
    else:
        await client.say("Cannot add that role")
```